# Hide disabled bootstrap button with css

Tags: html, css

I have few bootstrap buttons which will be enabled or disabled based on some criteria. I would like to hide 2 of the buttons when they are disabled. How can I achieve that using css.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adhikari18/7sb50xx2/)**

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn disabled">Disabled</button>
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what we are dealing with rather than shooting in the dark and guessing.

Comment: updated both question and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

**CSS3**

```
button.disabled{
display: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn disabled">Disabled</button>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/7zdcbLb0/4/)**

Comment: The button didn't have disabled attribute so this approach didn't work.

Comment: @adhikari18 then how are they disabled?

Comment: So add a class to the button when is disabled - I update my answer

Answer (score 4):

For those coming to find answers to hiding a button with the disabled attribute:

```
<button class="some-class" disabled>
```

You can use the pseudo :disabled

```
button:disabled {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
button:disabled
{
  display: none;
}
```